# Strange error in db call javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactoryException: Resource javax/sql/rowset/rowset.properties not found

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8

While trying to make a db call i am getting below error, If anyone come across this one and resolved ?

```
Caused by: javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactoryException: Resource javax/sql/rowset/rowset.properties not found
        at javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactory.lambda$initMapIfNecessary$0(SyncFactory.java:393)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactory.initMapIfNecessary(SyncFactory.java:388)
        at javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactory.getInstance(SyncFactory.java:557)
        at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.<init>(CachedRowSetImpl.java:361)
        at com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl.createCachedRowSet(RowSetFactoryImpl.java:49)
```

Adding snippets,

```
  private CachedRowSet getRowSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        CachedRowSet results = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
        results.populate(resultSet);
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Please post relevant code to reproduce this.

Comment: Sorry, I could not post it because my company policies wont allow that. But i am sure its normal JDBC call.

Comment: It isn't, because a row set is only created if you create it explicitly. Normal JDBC does not involve row sets. And if your company disallows posting the actual code, then you need to recreate it in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Added snippets, yes i am converting result to rowset, initially its worked fine only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but calling CachedRowSet explicitly solves the issue. Any proper answer will be appreciated.

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    Class<CachedRowSet> doNOTdelete = CachedRowSet.class;
    load();
}
```